# USB modem doesn't get connected

Tags: usb-modem

I'm using the 3.5G Hsdpa modem, it has been detected as an usb modem. But when I try to connect, it always *disconnected*. I've tried to use Wvdial & Sakis3G but it still can't connect.

I don't think this is a signal or a device problem since it it connects normally with Windows even when the signal is very low.

Answer (score 1):

Try Sakis3G with some switches:

```
--pppd 
--nostorage
--nofix
--nohal
```

One of these may solve your problem. If not, try `--interactive` to manually configure your modem.